# Getting complex CAD drawing to right location in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, georeferencing

I have a complex CAD drawing from a city with many layers..hatches, points, poliylines..and I need it to georeference because when I import the DWG file into QGIS it turns out to be at the wrong place.

I am new to GIS, so I seek ideas. I will attach imagery below.

[image: @]

Comment: In what coordinate reference system was the CAD document captured?  In what CRS do you want it displayed?

Comment: Thank you for your response! There is no CRS assigned to it. I want to project it onto Google maps and the city is in Turkey. How do I know wich CRS to use?

Comment: Finding the right CRS for an unknown dataset is a matter of trial and error. Start with CRS's that are designed for Turkey: https://epsg.io/?q=turkey

Comment: Let's say I want the drawing to be in EPSG:4326 WGS 84. Shall i assign a CRS designed for Turkey (e.g.: TUREF / LCC Europe) to the CAD drawing and then chose the EPSG:4326 WGS 84 when importing in QGis or how do I do it?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found the correct CRS.